# how to give privilege for global variable write in mysql like slow_query_log?

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

When I create slow_query_log rotation, I need one user for set & update slow_query_log as On and Off. How can I give permission for only this query or global variable access to user?

Answer (score 0):

```
FLUSH SLOW LOGS;
```

was added in 5.5.3.

> SLOW closes and reopens the slow query log file.

If you are on a *nix OS, *first* you `mv` the log file to a new name on the same filesystem (as part of the "rotation" script), *then* you issue `FLUSH ...`.  Through the magic of the way Unix files work, nothing is lost.  `mysqld` continues to write to the old file, even though the *name* has changed.  Then the `FLUSH` causes `mysqld` to stop writing to it, and write to a new file.  (Windows is another matter.)

You could use `mysqladmin` instead of `mysql`.

I would create a new user with the minimal privileges for this action.  (I think it is just `RELOAD`.)